# Inner JScrollPane Inside a JScrollPane Is Not Working Properly

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

I'm trying to create a container with scrollbar and inside the container have two inner panel inside. Inside the top inner panel are also having another JScrollPane.

But currently I'm facing the issue when my top inner panel is too long (width) the scroll bar inside the top inner panel is disable, I only able to scroll the scroll bar of the container.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestFrame {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("Hello-" + i));
        }
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel contentPaneSub = new JPanel();
        contentPaneSub.add(scrollPane);

        contentPane.add(contentPaneSub, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        centerPanel.add(new JButton("Example"));
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(contentPane);
        scrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane1);
        //for demo purpose we set this using hard coded way
        //in real life project the java will auto adjust it size based on windows resolution
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 160));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What I hope to get is  if the top inner panel is too long in width then the scroll bar inside the top inner panel will be visible and allow to scroll. Not the scrollbar in the container.

Comment: Do you want the "Hello" panel to dynamically resize itself to stay inside the outer panel? You could fix your problem by locking the "Hello" panel to a fixed width that is less than or equal to the frame's width, however, this would mean the "Hello" panel would remain that width even if you expanded or contracted the window.

Comment: @MihirKekkar Thanks for reply. Yes, I wish my "Hello" panel will be fixed the sized within the outer panel. but is there any way which the thing can be done dynamically and get the accurate width and height based on the size assigning to the "Hello" panel? I don't want to do it by specifying setSize(100,200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different issues I came across trying to solve this problem. The first was having the `JScrollPane` be contained within the window, and the second was getting the resizing of the `JScrollPane` to be dynamic.

I was able to solve the first issue but not completely solve the second one using a custom class. The `JScrollPane` dynamically increase its width as the window increase, but it does not dynamically shrink with the window size. This is because when the window size decreases, the outer `JScrollPane` locks the width of the content inside, including the inner `JScrollPane`.

I was unable to find a way to get the inner pane to shrink dynamically without effectively removing the functionality of the outer pane, which doesn't work because your question was specifically for a `JScrollPane` within another functional `JScrollPane`.

```
public class TestFrame {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("Hello-" + i));
        }

        MyCustomPane scrollPane = new MyCustomPane(panel); //changed this line

        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel contentPaneSub = new JPanel();
        contentPaneSub.add(scrollPane);

        scrollPane.setOuterContainer(contentPaneSub); //added this line

        contentPane.add(contentPaneSub, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        centerPanel.add(new JButton("Example"));
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(contentPane);
        scrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane1);
        //for demo purpose we set this using hard coded way
        //in real life project the java will auto adjust it size based on windows resolution
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 160));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code for the MyCustomPane class:

```
public class MyCustomPane extends JScrollPane {
    Container outerContainer;

    public MyCustomPane(Component view) {
        super(view);
    }

    public void setOuterContainer(Container outerContainer) {
        this.outerContainer = outerContainer;
    }

    private Dimension getCustomDimensions() {
        if (outerContainer == null) {
            return new Dimension(0, 0);
        }
        return new Dimension(outerContainer.getWidth() - 10, 60); //10 pixels less than container width, arbitrary height
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return getCustomDimensions();
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getCustomDimensions();
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return getCustomDimensions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. That solution did solve my issue but at the end I use formlayout to control the width to be no grow for  the inner panel.